# Splitting up pybind11 modules and issues with automatic type conversion

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I have a set of modules that I've written in C++ and exported to Python using pybind11. All of these modules should be able to be used independently, but they use a common set of custom types that are defined in a utility library.

In each module there is code something like what's below. The `Color.hpp` header defines the types that are used in the utility library.

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <string>
#include "Color.hpp"

std::vector<Color> buncha_colors(int n, std::string &color) {
    std::vector<Color> out;
    for (;n-- > 0;) {
        out.push_back(Color(color));
    }
    return out;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(pb11_example_module, m) {
    m.def("buncha_colors", &buncha_colors);
}
```

Of course, this doesn't work. Pybind does not know how to do the type conversion for a `Color` object. The answer (or hopefully not) is to define the `Color` class as a part of the module. Afterwards, pybind is capable of doing the automatic type conversion.

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <string>
#include "Colors.hpp"

std::vector<Color> buncha_colors(int n, std::string &color) {
    std::vector<Color> out;
    for (;n-- > 0;) {
        out.push_back(Color(color));
    }
    return out;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(pb11_example_module, m) {
    pybind11::class_<Color>(m, "Color")
        .def(pybind11::init<std::string&>())
        .def("name", &Color::name);
    m.def("buncha_colors", &buncha_colors);
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to keep all these custom utility types and associated functions in a separate module from all the modules that use them. But I'd need to define the type conversions, or otherwise reference it, in every module that uses it. How do I go about this? I don't want `pb11_example_module.Color` and `utils.Color` and so on. I have no idea about their compatibility for one, and it just seems like the wrong way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This started out as an edit, but has turned out to be my answer.

So this is interesting. Using the first example where `Color` is not exported in the pybind module...

```
$ python
>>> import pb11_example_module
>>> pb11_example_module.buncha_colors(10, "red")[0].name()
TypeError: Unable to convert function return value to a Python type! The signature was
    (arg0: int, arg1: str) -> List[Color]
>>> import utils  # defines Color
>>> pb11_example_module.buncha_colors(10, "red")[0].name()
'red'
```

Importing the utility library before importing the example module also works. Changing the class name `"Color"` to something else doesn't break the usage either, so it must be picking up the type conversion from the other module using the type signature.

As long as a type conversion for that C++ type is defined before use, automatic type conversion works. The type conversion utilities that pybind uses for Python are global and looked-up at runtime. You can read all about it [here](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/custom.html). The above solution of loading a type conversion for the custom type at any point before usage is the supported idiomatic solution.

Comment: Just to follow-up, I think the more idomatic solution (in your bindings) is to ensure that you've imported the module using `py::module::import("my_package.my_depdendency")`. Ultimately, b/c you're doing bindings with that global registry you mentioned, importing modules has a side effect - registering the type via RTTI. If you import the module dependency in your bindings, then you're good to go. Here's an example PR + test which fails fast if that's forgotten (for our code): https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/14072/files

Comment: @EricCousineau Great tip!